# Is it possible to change the .apk file to NOT debuggable after packaging?

Tags: android, packaging

I have made an app that I would like to upload to google play, but it is still in debuggable mode. (I can only package it with this setting.) Is there a method to change it or is it impossible?

Comment: If you can only package it with the debuggable flag set, it sounds like there's an issue with your build process. Why can't you change that?

Comment: I think that is not possible, Why can't you repackage app without debuggable flag?